# How to make sliderInput R UI drag in either direction when min equals max

Tags: r, shiny, slider

Using R shiny, I have a sliderInput in my UI with handles for min and for max values. These work as expected...mostly. If you click the min handle and drag it to the same value as the max handle, a single handle appears on that value -- e.g. if max was 5 and you drag the min handle to 5, now you have a single handle at 5 representing both min and max.

All fine so far, but now, if you click the handle at 5 and try to drag it right, the UI won't allow you to. The only way around this is to drag the min down again (to say, 4, maybe) and then go back to the remaining handle and drag it right again.

Is this the intended behavior? Is there any way I can make it so that the UI knows which handle I want to move based on the direction I'm moving when the handles are overlapping one another?

Code below shows the sliderInput behavior I mention.

```
library(shiny)

ui <-
  fluidPage(fluidRow(column(
    12,
    sliderInput(
      inputId = "foo_bar",
      label = "Select Range",
      min = 0,
      max = 10,
      value = c(0, 10),
      step = 1,
      round = T,
      ticks = T,
      width = "100%",
      dragRange = T
    )
  )))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = function(input, output) {})
```

Comment: Do you mean that when min is equal to max you can drag the handle left but not right? It works for me as expected and I can drag it in both the directions.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Strange you aren't recreating it.

Comment: I am recreating it - the essential piece to recreating the problem (for me anyway) is that it's dependent on the last slider I moved. If I move the min to match the max, I can't then move it right. If I match max to the min, I can't then move it left. After matching the sliders, though, if I click (rather than drag) anywhere else on the line, both sliders move. (This is also true when the sliders aren't matched.) Not sure if that's a simple workaround, or if you want the dragging capability?

Comment: @phalteman, thanks, I didn't realize that clicking elsewhere would move both handles. Even so, yes, ideally they would be dragged together, if nothing else because I find that more intuitive.